# Recover file from a file

Tags: windows, gratis, offline, forensics

There are tools to recover files from broken hard disks, USB sticks or SD cards. I have an OLE file that was extracted from a Word document. That OLE file seems to contain a video.

I'm looking for a program that can find files in files and extract them.

I have tried:

- [Foremost](https://sourceforge.net/projects/foremost/) but that tool does neither offer help with the `/?` command line switch nor is there any documentation on the website.

Comment: By Word document, do you mean `doc` or `docx`? If it's a `docx` file, you could rename the extension to `zip` and explore its contents.

Comment: @ÉbeIsaac: that's exactly what I did to get the OLE file out of the word document. Now I need to get the video out of the OLE document. It's a file in a file in a file :-(

Comment: Feels like *Inception*.  Conceptually it is just an overlay of headers. Each item encapsulates the other file in its payload. Did you try studying the schematics of the OLE file format?

Comment: @ÉbeIsaac: I did not yet look into the internals of that file format. Basically I'm interested, but I don't have the time to do it. That's why I'm looking for a tool that helps me.

Comment: Didn't test, but [olebrowse](https://www.decalage.info/python/olebrowse) claims to be able to do it.